# Make HDFS calulcate checksum for local file.

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, checksum

I'm trying to calculate a local file checksum using `hadoop fs -checksum`. But it only returns None.

`[centos@sandbox tmp]$ hadoop fs -checksum file:///user/centos//a.json
file:///user/centos/a.json  NONE`

I have tried using

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal a.json file:///user/centos/a.json` Such that in local folder `/user/centos` generate a `.a.json.crc file`. But the result checksum is still returns none.

How to make Hadoop calculate checksum locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hadoop fs -checksum` currently does not have the capability to calculate a checksum on a file from the local file system.  Potential workarounds are:

- Apache JIRA [HADOOP-12326](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12326) tracks supporting files on the local file system as a target of the `hadoop fs -checksum` command.  If you really need the capability now, then you could potentially download the Hadoop source, apply the patch attached to HADOOP-12326, and create a custom build by following the directions in [BUILDING.txt](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/BUILDING.txt).  Please be aware that the patch is not yet approved and committed by the Apache Hadoop community, so use at your own risk.
- If you are simply looking for a way to carry CRC information with you when you copy a file out of HDFS onto the local file system, then you could pass the `-crc` argument to the `get` command.

**Example:**

```
hadoop fs -get -crc hello

ls -lrta 
...
-rw-r--r--   1 cnauroth                    cnauroth                       12 Jun 23 15:28 .hello.crc
-rw-r--r--   1 cnauroth                    cnauroth                        6 Jun 23 15:28 hello
...
```